# How can I avoid using a variable here?

Tags: javascript, dom, variables

I want to create a canvas element and get it's context. I tried everything, but can't get rid of the `buffer` variable. It's driving me insane. Can you help me?

```
(function(buffer){
    document.body.appendChild(
        buffer=document.createElement("canvas")
    )
    canvas=buffer.getContext("2d")
})()
```

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with the variable? Anyways, you can do:

```
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"))
              .getContext("2d");
```

since `Node.appendChild` returns the node that was appended.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I just don't like using unnecessary variables because you have to put a function around the piece of code to avoid polluting the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like that?

```
(function(){
    var buffer = document.createElement("canvas");
    document.body.appendChild( buffer );

    var canvas = buffer.getContext("2d")

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
(function(buffer){

    var canvas;
    document.body.appendChild(buffer)
    canvas = buffer.getContext("2d")

})(document.createElement("canvas"))
```